# What's going on with code blocks?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

```
Is
this
how
code
blocks
should
look?
```

In addition to the [lack of syntax highlighting](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/11524) >:(, it... looks like inline code! How about a unified rectangle instead? Put the border on the `<pre>`, not `<code>`.

```
enter preformatted text here
```

^ Why not "enter code here"?

Also, while writing this meta post "draft saved" would pop up in the top left corner and it seems to be lacking `position: absolute` or something since it pushed my codeblock right until it vanished about 5s later.

fixthecssfixthecssfixthecss!

## For those from the future

(ew, no left-padding for the header)

hi. Is the Apple Watch 2 any good? iPhone streeeetch? Anyway, screenshot of the horrible look as of 2014-09-10:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Link to the source](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/revisions/ca8f4064-7d2d-4890-beca-84fcfca3a46f/view-source).

Comment: Think that's a bug with the new theme...

Comment: Hope they fix this as its really tough to read and distracting.....

Comment: i'm fixing this now.

Comment: @Jin Could we get some margin on the bottom of the `pre` as well please. They have no white space before any following paragraph.

Comment: @DanielBallinger yes. salesforce.se is launched on a new CSS/LESS structure I've been working on. So there are still little quirks I'm finding out. We'll be doing another production build later tonight to get the changes out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this. It will be on live after our next production build.

Comment: Looks like the width and margin has been fixed, but the whitespace in between the lines of code is still there.  Is that going to be fixed as well?

Comment: All looks good to me on Chrome.

Comment: Can `.wmd-preview` get some padding? `3px`?